# Проблема с установкой npm

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm, node-modules

Всем привет.Кто может подсказать - маюсь с установкой npm-пакетов в node. На любой пакет ругается вот так

```
$ npm install uglify-js --global
npm ERR! Unexpected token <

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Server\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-18T13_33_55_974Z-debug.log
```

а при попытке загрузить список пакетов в `webstorm 2017.1` после долгой паузы пишет, что `не может подключиться к registry.npmjs.org`.
Кто знает в чем может быть проблема и как исправить?

Comment: Это происходит если сам npm лежит или если жестоко побилась установка пакета в неудобное время. Надо как минимум проверить доступность npm, почистить кеши (npm cache clean). Еще говорят бывает при сидении через ненастроенный прокси

Comment: я пробовал npm cache clean , у меня даже на него вылезает такая же ошибка. пакеты пробовал ставить разные, на все одно и то же.пробую весь день сегодняшний.А на тему прокси - я вообще не использую его.В сети с модема МТС, ввиду того, что нахожусь в тюрьме и сюда выделенный канал не дают провести.-)

Comment: нужно запустить консоль "из под администратора"

Comment: частично решил - проблема была в том, что я запускал консоль не в system32, а в директории node.пакеты ставятся через консоль.но вот если пробовать ставить npm через встроенную функцию webstorm, то он выдает, что возникла ошибка подключения к regisrty.npmjs.org.Так что если есть мысли как решить эту проблему, то с радостью буду их слушать